# Open and interact with android application from command line

Tags: android, linux

I've loaded Android onto VirtualBox and would like to do the following:

1) Via the command line (Terminal Emulator), open up a downloaded app (call it Lyft)
2) Interact with the app as if I were a user working with the app normally on a phone --

2a) Pass my username/password to log in
OR
2b) Pass in new account credentials to create a new account

I imagine this thing is possible, given that Android is just a modified version of Linux but I'm not entirely sure where to get started.  How could one do this sort of thing to emulate the experience of using the mobile app, without an API and without actually touching a phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) to create a script that does all you want. `culebra --gui` can also be used to create the script just pointing and clicking on the UI (check https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/wiki/Culebra-GUI).

Comment: This looks incredible and, if not exactly what I'm looking for, a hell of a great start. Thank yoh

Comment: Great. There are some videos at http://dtmilano.blogspot.com that would help you understand its capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

You can launch the app , but accessing input fields is possible if the login form fields request focus immediately after launching . Otherwise , an interaction to click on the form field is a must

For launching the app , go to the android sdk directory or if its added to the path - connect the phone and run

```
adb shell
adb shell monkey -p com.android.chrome -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER 1
```

where com.android.chrome should be replaced by the package name of the app you want to launch